# PDFLib Error "create_pvf: No data supplied (size=0)"

Tags: php, pdflib

My PHP application throws the exception on a Linux production system, on Windows everything works fine.

Does anyone know the reason for that error message?

I use PDFlib 7...

Answer (score 0):

looks like, the parameter data for the create_pvf() do not contain any content. So you should search before, why this differs to the Windows environment.

Maybe some file read operations failed, due to different paths.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem: the input data for the function were NULL...